# What's my error?

Tags: java

So I'm coding a Minecraft mod, though I am very new to Java and coding in general. So I have 2 classes:

#### InGameGUI class

```js
package kaelinatorclickingspeedmod;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen;

public class InGameGUI extends GuiScreen{

 public InGameGUI() {
  this.mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
 }
int clicks = Mod.clicks;

 public void renderScreen(){
  mc.fontRendererObj.drawString(String.valueOf(clicks), 305, 232, 0x0026FF);
 }
}
```

#### Mod Class

```js
package kaelinatorclickingspeedmod;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import io.netty.util.Timer;

public class Mod implements MouseListener {
private static InGameGUI 
inGameGUI = new InGameGUI();
public static InGameGUI getInGameGUI() {
 return inGameGUI;

}


public static int clicks=0;

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
 clicks++;
}
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

}
```

Anyway, what I was expecting to happen was that it would add 1 for every time I click starting from 0. But what really happens is that it just stays at a 0. Nothing is changed when I click. Is it because it is a static int? For me to be able to call "clicks" from Mod to InGameGUI it has to be a static int. But is there another way to call it? Could I use a get command? Is it because I need some sort of continue command? Thanks!

EDIT: Even when I change clicks default to 1, it still displays 0.

Comment: Try adding a System.out.println("Somestring"); in your mouseClicked method before the if statement, to make sure it is being called. Also add one inside the body of that if statement to make sure BUTTON1 is the one you want.

Comment: Also, I have no idea how MineCraft mods work, but do you need to register your class as a MouseListener somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In your InGameGUI class, you should use `String.valueof(Mod.clicks)` in `renderScreen` and ditch the other `clicks` variable. Ints are value types, so each one has its own location on the stack. In other words, when mouse clicks update `Mod.clicks`, the InGameGUI `clicks` variable doesn't get updated, and that's the one you're attempting to print.

Comment: Ok, so by putting "Mod.clicks" where "clicks" was in the "String.valueof()" command, it now displays the number if I change "clicks" to a different number, so that's good. But what do you mean by saying ditch the other clicks variable? And is that how I am suppose to make InGameGUI update?

Comment: The clicks variable in InGameGUI doesn't seem to serve a purpose. For the other part of your question, someone familiar with Minecraft modding will have to answer. It's not really clear from your question how renderScreen is called.